# Iptables for Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, apache, security, firewall, iptables

Usually when we configure iptables rules for a website, we accept incoming connections to HTTP and HTTPS ports.

In the case of Wordpress, the CMS also makes HTTP and HTTPS connections to wordpress.org (for example, when you search for a plugin in the dashboard or you try to make an update of Wordpress)

HTTP/HTTPS connections are also needed when upgrading your system via apt-get or yum.

Since I am not comfortable just allowing all HTTP/HTTPS outgoing connections from a server, do you have any ideas on how to let you system or Wordpress make HTTP/HTTPS connections in a safer manner?

Regards,

Comment: Did you ever manage to add solid outgoing rule for connection to WordPress.org for plugins to be displayed for installation and such? I seem to have issues now as well going to wp-admin/plugin-install.php on a Plesk setup with transip.nl firewall

Answer (score 0):

You can make WordPress use a proxy for outgoing connections, if you don't mind running one somewhere, which would also allow you to filter the traffic to catch misbehaving plugins. You might run into trouble with older plugins that don't use the HTTP API, but I haven't met any in quite some time.

Comment: The solution should be implemented at firewall level. Right now I couldn't use a proxy.